# Bad practises in abstract classes C#

Tags: c#, abstract

I'm trying to improve my coding standards by implementing interfaces and abstract classes when necessary, however I would like to ask about practises regarding abstract classes.

I'm creating a web application and one aspect of the site I need to do some data processing, I have created an abstract class and it looks something like this.

```
public abstract class TestAbstractClass
{
  public abstract void doDataProcessing();
}
```

And I need to implement this 'doDataProcessing' method a few times throughout the application dependent on where the user is on my site, it will do VERY similar data processing, just with one or two different things.

For example:

User is on certain page:

```
public Page1Class: TestAbstractClass
{
  public override void doDataProcessing()
  {
    //do data processing
  }
}
```

User is on another page

```
public Page2Class: TestAbstractClass
{
  public override void doDataProcessing()
  {
    //do data processing but with slight change
  }
}
```

User is on another page

```
public Page3Class: TestAbstractClass
{
  public override void doDataProcessing()
  {
    //do data processing but with another change
  }
}
```

Would this be best practise? Or is it better just making one class, and just doing various conditional statements on what is being passed into the 'doDataProcessing()' method?

I feel if I do it using the method I have posted, I will be having a lot of duplicate code in these 3 classes, is that OK?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You can have implementation in an abstract class/method btw.

Comment: Personally, I'd use an interface for this, unless there is a need for some code in the base class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Answer (score 6):

This feels like you need to decompose the solution a bit more. `doDataProcessing` sounds like it is something that could be broken into smaller pieces. There are high-level design patterns that could help you structure this.

If `doDataProcessing` is a similar thing but with small changes, then look at the [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) or the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: The Strategy pattern looks good, but whenever 'doDataProcessing' is executed, I need to execute another method before hand in every circumstance, which is always the same. That is why I used an abstract class as I created the implementation for that method in there. What would you recommend in this situation?

Comment: A method before hand (which is always the same)? I might do something like `public void doDataProcessing() { doTheAlwaysThing(); _internalDoDataProcessing(); }` (rename the version of `doDataProcessing` to something internal and make the public version the real version).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to have any implementation in the base doDataProcessing then just go with an interface as @phuzi recommended. Abstract classes are best used if you have some logic that is exactly the same in most cases, and in odd scenarios you can override and/or extend the base logic in the inherited classes.

EDIT

From the information you gave me I would probably do the following:

```
public abstract class TestAbstractClass
{
  public void Process()
  {
     MethodThatGetsCalledEveryTime();
     doDataProcessing();
  }

  public virtual void doDataProcessing()
  {
      // can add frequent logic here
  }

  protected void MethodThatGetsCalledEveryTime()
  {
      // do stuff here
  }
}
```

this way you can ensure that the "MethodThatGetsCalledEveryTime" will always be called, and if you add additional logic to doDataProcessing that will run as well from the appropriate place.

Comment: I do have an implementation in the abstract class which is a method which is executed every time doDataProcessing is run.

Comment: see my edit @user3046756

Comment: Thank you, this has simplified my code some :)